# The motion of a spring due to wind (Wind induced oscillations)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, spring, oscillators, turbulence, fan

Consider a spring held in the direction of wind as shown in the image. the spring body is wrapped with paper so that the spring oscillates with the wind in a circular manner. Is there any mathematical model to describe this motion. I have studied wind induced oscillation but i do not understand how the spring oscillates with the wind. I have kept a small counterweight at the tail end of the spring, this is to increase the tension of the member[image: []

Comment: It's not completely clear how the experiment is working - are you talking about longitudinal (left-right) or torsional (twisting) excitations? Also, is the fan blowing or sucking?

Comment: It's rotary motion and the fan is blowing...I wish I could put the video here but there is no option for that..instead I suggest you to visit my YouTube page which is priyo Coutinho there i have posted a video of this experiment..and just to be clear i have given you my YouTube username only for educational purpose i have no intention of getting suscribers..i would like if you could help me out here..thankyou